# Angularjs issue with directive unchecking all checkboxes

Tags: angularjs

Hello and thank you for looking at my issue.

I am creating a directive that simply list parents and their children. Each parent have a checkbox available to allow user to print the parents indeed checked (examples: if user check parent #1 and #5, only #1 and #5 will be printed ). I also have a filter the allow users to "filter" parents (over 100 of them).

The issue is with the checkboxes: I would like that the filter ( a drop down ) when selected would clear all checkboxes. Right now if user checks parent #1 and #5 and filter out 5, #1 stays checked. I am adding my code below.
Thanks so much for helping me...

```
app.directive('isolateScopeWithController', function () {

var controller = ['$scope', 'treeFactory', '$q', function ($scope, treeFactory, $q) {

    var vm = this;

    $scope.ocw = "";

    $scope.types = [
                   {description : "All Parent", type : 2},
                   {description : "True Parent", type : 1},
                   {description : "Parent", type : 0}
               ];

     $scope.$watch('selectedType', function(){          
        // I wish I would have this function working
        uncheckAll();

    })

   function uncheckAll() {
        // uncheck all the  check box currently checked 
        // cannot do it!
    }

    init();

    function init(){

        $scope.selectedType = "2";

        $scope.ocw = {
         "parents":[
         {name: "parent1", "type": 0, children: ["name": "child1", "name": "child2"]},
         {name: "parent2", "type": 0, children: ["name": "child3", "name": "child4"]},
         ...
         {name: "parent5", "type": 1, children: ["name": "child10", "name": "child11"]}
         ]
        }
    }
    ],

  template = '<div>'+
                 '<div>'+
                    '<select ng-model="selectedType" ng-change="update(selectedType)">'+
                        '<option ng-repeat="x in types" value="{{x.type}}">{{x.description}}</option>'+
                    '</select>'+                        
                 '</div>'+                      
                 '<div>'+
                    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-primary" ng-click="printParentschecked(ocw)"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span> Print Selected </button>'+
                 '</div>'+
             '</div>'+
                 '<div ng-repeat="parent in ocw.parents" class="col-sm-8">'+
                    '<div ng-if="filterType(parent.type)">'+    
                         '<div class="row">'+
                            '<div class="col-sm-8">'+
                                '<span>{{parent.name}}</span>'+
                            '</div>'+
                            '<div class="col-sm-2">'+
                                '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="parent.isOpenValue" ng-click="checked(parent.name)" >'+
                            '</div>'+
                         '</div>'+
                        '<div ng-repeat="org in parent.children" class="col-sm-8">'+
                            '{{children.name}}'+
                        '</div>'
                    '</div>'+       
                 '</div>'+

             '</div>';
  return {
      restrict: 'E', 
      replace: true,
      scope: {},
      controller: controller,
      template: template,   
      transclude: true,
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, transclude) {
                scope.printParentschecked = function(ocw){
                    // print the checked parents... I can do it!
                }
                scope.filterType = function(type) {
                    //it works, it checks the value selected in the drop down and the type of the parent
                    // if they match they are shown
                if (types === 1 && type === 1) {
                    return true;
                }
                ....


          }  
      }
  };
});
```

P.S. probably the real issue is that I do not really understand angular directives :(

Comment: There seems to be a syntax error after the `init()` definition- there's `],`, which should probably be `}];` as the end of your `controller` definition. This probably won't solve your main problem, but you still need syntactically correct code for _any_ solution to really work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  function uncheckAll() {
              angular.forEach(ocw.parents,function(parent,key){                  
                       parent.isOpenValue=false;        
                      }
            }
```

Comment: Great answer Sreehari!  Four lines that saved my day! Thanks!